# Get vdb motion blur in blender (from embergen)

Tags: volumetrics, motion-blur

I made a basic fire and smoke simulation in embergen and exported it as a vdb sequence (with the velocity data). When I put it into blender I get three velocity float values instead of one float vector value.

The  problem is that I don't get any motion blur on this sim when I render it.

Any Idea how to get it right ? I tried using the vector pass to get the motion blur in the compositor but it doesn't seem to do anything, which doesn't surprise me that much ...

Ps : second screenshot is from a tutorial where it shows how my vector is supposed to look

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to export the velocity as **one single grid** containing vector values, not individual floats for each direction (float vector means XYZ in one grid). Not sure whether there is a way combining the float values in blender though.

Comment: I merged them but it still does not work...

Answer (score 0):

The things that you're doing are probably correct (the second image) but motion blur with VDB files has been broken for a long time in Blender.

This was a report for liquids but it is the same for volumes:https://developer.blender.org/T78442